# ¿Cómo corregir el nombre de una etiqueta?

Tags: soporte

Eso, quiero corregir la etiqueta [i8n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i8n), lo correcto debe ser [i18n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i18n) de "Internationalization":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los nombres de las etiquetas no se pueden editar, sólo el wiki de las mismas.

Cuando un nombre de etiqueta está mal, hay que crear una nueva etiqueta con el nombre correcto y cambiar las etiquetas de las preguntas que usan la etiqueta incorrecta.

En relación a lo que va ocurrir con la etiqueta con nombre incorrecto, los sitios de la red de Stack Exchange tienen scripts que realizan tareas de depuración de forma periódica. Una de estas tareas es la de eliminar las etiquetas sin preguntas. En algunos la frecuencia es diaria y en otros de varias semanas.

Comment: La respuesta que esperaba, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente editala. Eso es lo unico que tienes que hacer.

Comment: Es lo obvio, lo intenté. No veo por ningún lado como cambiar el nombre de la etiqueta solo la información o descripción

Comment: @CésarBustíos ve a la pregunta que tiene la etiqueta y editala! Las etiquetas (tags) no existen si no hay preguntas asociadas a estas.

Comment: Pues, no veo ninguna pregunta relacionada. Por eso preguntaba si es posible editar la etiqueta o eliminarla en todo caso

Comment: @CésarBustíos porque [yo ya edite la unica](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/989) pregunta que tenia asignada la etiqueta.

Comment: Oh! Y entonces, ¿qué se hace con una etiqueta inválida?

Comment: @CésarBustíos nada. El sistema se encarga.

Comment: Ya veo. Entonces no existe forma de editar el nombre de la etiqueta _per se_

Comment: @CésarBustíos  Las etiquetas sirven para conectar las preguntas con los usuarios que saben las repuestas. Sin preguntas no hay etiquetas.